# How do I find corrupted archive files?

Tags: bash, zip

I have a lot of zip files. Some are not downloaded correctly and are corrupted. I want to remove them.

Is there a way to find the corrupted archives in bash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU (for `-readable` and `-iname`) find:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -type f -readable ! -exec unzip -t {} \; -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. a question: what does \! do?

Comment: @Nima It's a logical not operator, ie. if `unzip -t {}` fails, exec `rm -i {}`. It has to be escaped because by default `!` is used for history expansion in `bash`.

Comment: @ChrisDown Is there actually a shell that doesn't treat `!` literally when it's followed by a space? I have the habit of writing `\!` too, but I thought it was out of habit (because `!` has to be quoted in so many places in bash), not out of necessity.

Comment: @Gilles - Good point! I don't know of any. I guess this goes also to the manual pages saying that `{}` needs escaping...

Comment: maybe @Nima wants to remove the files manualy then using `-print0` instead of `exec rm -i {} \;` will display the files that are corrupted without deleting them.

Comment: @Gilles. Good point, if `! ` needed escaping then things like `[ ! -f x ]` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The following will print the name of all corrupted zip files in the current directory and its subdirectories:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob nullglob globstar
for file in ./**/*.zip; do
    [[ -r $file ]] || continue
    unzip -t "$file" >/dev/null 2>&1 || printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

If you wish to remove them, simply replace `printf '%s\n' "$file"` with `rm -f "$file"`.

Comment: Beware though that it's not the same permissions that apply to read a file and to delete it, so you may end up deleting a file just because you don't have the right to read it. Also note that bash recursive globbing (contrary to other shells) descends into symlinks to directories which is generally not what you want. Also, you may want to write it `./**/*.zip` to avoid problems with file/dir names starting with "-".

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - Good point, added in a read check.

Answer (score 0):

To find the corrupted archives in bash, I use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# change myfolder value below fully
myfolder="/Users/nathan/Downloads/some folder"

cd "$myfolder"

rm -f testlog.sh
rm -f testlog.txt

SQ="'"

find . -type f -iname '*.zip' -print | while read line
do
echo "unzip -t ${SQ}${line}${SQ}" | tee -a testlog.sh 2>&1;
done

bash testlog.sh | tee -a testlog.txt 2>&1;

totalcommands=$(wc -l testlog.sh|awk '{print $1}')
totalstatus=$(grep -o "No errors detected in compressed data of " testlog.txt | grep -c "")

echo
if [ $totalcommands -eq $totalstatus ]; then
echo "-------------------------------"
echo "All Tests Returned Success !!!!"
echo "-------------------------------"
else
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Some Tests Failed. Please check the ${SQ}${myfolder}/testlog.txt${SQ} file."
echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
fi
echo
```

Hope this helps.